# ROllback Commit on inerting Datagridview Rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datacontext

> Here is my code if each row data incorrect then all rows rollback in
>   my code problem is when 1st row okay the its inserted in DB but next
>   can't and rollback can't work

```
DateTime da = new DateTime();
da = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    using (DsourceDataContext dc = new DsourceDataContext())
    {
        using (TransactionScope tscope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            custompacking1 category = new custompacking1();
            {
                Double val3 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["fro"].Value);
                //Double val4 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["too"].Value.ToString());
                Double val5 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["gwt"].Value.ToString());
                Double val6 = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["nwt"].Value.ToString());

                category.cid = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["cid"].Value);
                category.tid = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["tid"].Value);
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["fro"].Value != null)
                {
                    category.fro = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["fro"].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    category.fro = 0;
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["too"].Value != null)
                {
                    category.too = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["too"].Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    category.too = "";
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["gwt"].Value != null)
                {
                    category.grosswt = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["gwt"].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    category.grosswt = 0;
                }
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["nwt"].Value != null)
                {
                    category.netwt = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["nwt"].Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    category.netwt = 0;
                }
                category.date2 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                category.date1 = da.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                category.gsmpcs = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["gpcs"].Value.ToString();
            }

            dc.custompacking1s.InsertOnSubmit(category);
            dc.SubmitChanges();
            //dc.Dispose();
            tscope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Inserted");
```

> m also use transactionscope with help of this forums but it can't
>   working

Answer (score 0):

Of course it won't rollback since, while, inserting into DB, if all values are incorrect, a rollback occurs, but even if one row is correct, that value is inputted into DB, in which case you would have to manually do rollback within the code.
Use an 'if' statement to check for `datarow1.fill()` is true, and if it returns false, use delete option to erase the row affected recently

Comment: but i was did this thorugh transaction Rollback but transaction commit rollback need connection is it any way to rollback in above code without giving connection